# component-preload.js not called on sap webide personal edition

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I created component-preload.js file for minify and uglify of the code, but it's requested only when I deploy the app to ABAP Repository.
When I run the app from Sap webide it's not requested by the browser at all.
I wonder why is that and if there is a quick fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In URL delete parameters after index.html or how is your html called.

This will trigger the same behaviour as on SAP system.